# Need help on find the textbox in the newly opened window in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

```
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();     
driver.findElement(By.id("ImageButton5")).click();
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);                
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);                    
}
driver.findElement(By.id("txtEnterDescription")).sendKeys("Test");
driver.findElement(By.id("chklstAllprocedure_0")).click();
```

I used this code and I got the error as

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element
>   with id == txtEnterDescription (WARNING: The server did not provide
>   any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 30.05
>   seconds". The HTML code for this text box is ""

Please help me out of this

Comment: any reason that you are implicitely waiting 30 seconds? this is incredibly bad test technique. this is saying that the system under test, is _expected_ to have response times varying between 1-30 seconds

Answer (score 2):

you may face "NoSuchElementException" only in two case for sure.

```
 1.The Element is yet to be Loaded
     - Have an appropriate wait logic here.
 2. You may try to locate the element wrongly .
     - Double Check your Xpath/ID(what ever)
     - Make sure you are in the same frame where the element is present.If not, switch to the frame then.
```

Comment: I have checked it. I dont have frame id for the new window and I tried Xpath and also id and name,the same error appeared. kindly give me another solution... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are switching to the right window

Reason 1 : Just make sure you are switching to the right window

I have an utility method to switch to the required window as shown below

```
public class Utility 
{
    public static WebDriver getHandleToWindow(String title){

        //parentWindowHandle = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
        WebDriver popup = null;
        Set<String> windowIterator = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandles();
        System.err.println("No of windows :  " + windowIterator.size());
        for (String s : windowIterator) {
          String windowHandle = s; 
          popup = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().switchTo().window(windowHandle);
          System.out.println("Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
          System.out.println("Window Url : " + popup.getCurrentUrl());
          if (popup.getTitle().equals(title) ){
              System.out.println("Selected Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
              return popup;
          }

        }
                System.out.println("Window Title :" + popup.getTitle());
                System.out.println();
            return popup;
        }
}
```

It will take you to desired window once title of the window is passed as parameter. In your case you can do.

`Webdriver childDriver = Utility.getHandleToWindow("titleOfChildWindow");`

and then again switch to parent window using the same method

```
Webdriver parentDriver = Utility.getHandleToWindow("titleOfParentWindow");
```

This method works effectively when dealing with multiple windows

Resaon 2 : wait for the element

```
WebdriverWait wait = new  WebdriverWait(driver,7000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visbilityOfElementLocatedBy(By.name("nameofElement")));
```

Reason 3 : check if the element is in a frame if yes switch to the frame before

```
driver.switchTo.frame("frameName");
```

Let know if it works ..

Answer (score 0):

Guess the problem is in your switch to logic. I think when you are switching it is passing the code of the parent instead of the child. For this scenario create two local variables parent and child. Loop through the window handles using an iterator and set the parent and child window id's to the variables and pass the child id to the switchTo method. This should work. Keep me posted. Happy coding.